# Finding rows with sum of a column which is lower than a given value in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame (or data.table). I want to sort the rows in ascending order of a column and then select therows whose column value totals are just lower than a given value.

For example let's say I have the mtcars data frame. I've sorted the rows in increasing order of qsec column. Now I want to find rows whose sum of qsec values are lower than say 100. And if I add the next row the sum will exceed 100.

I wrote a while loop for this but I am looking for a better vectoral solution.

```
> head((mtcars[order(mtcars$qsec), ]))
                mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Ford Pantera L 15.8   8  351 264 4.22 3.17 14.50  0  1    5    4
Maserati Bora  15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.60  0  1    5    8
Camaro Z28     13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.84 15.41  0  0    3    4
Ferrari Dino   19.7   6  145 175 3.62 2.77 15.50  0  1    5    6
Duster 360     14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4
Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In data.table use `order` to arrange columns and the `cumsum` function to find the rows whose cumulative sum is less than your cutoff

```
library(data.table)
mtcars <- copy(mtcars)                            # because binding is locked
setDT(mtcars)                                     # convert to data.table   
setorder(mtcars, qsec)                            # reorder rows
out <- mtcars[cumsum(qsec) < 100]                 # filter rows
out
```

In the tidyverse use `arrange` to sort columns and `filter` to select rows by criteria

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% arrange(qsec) %>% filter(cumsum(qsec) < 100)
```

Comment: Or base R for reference: `mtcars <- mtcars[order(mtcars$qsec), ]; mtcars <- mtcars[cumsum(mtcars$qsec) < 100, ]`

Comment: The posted solutions drop the row names. In case of the `mtcars` dataset the row names contain the name of the cars. So, this might be considered an important information which shouldn't get lost (at least OP's expected result includes the row names).

Answer (score 2):

Here are `data.table` and `dplyr` solutions which preserve row names, i.e., the names of the cars, in line with OP's expected result.

Note that `data.table` as well as `tidyverse` drop the row names atttribute from data.frames by default. To keep the row names as part of a `data.table` or `tibble`, resp., this has to be requested explicitely.

#### `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars, key = "qsec", keep.rownames = TRUE)[cumsum(qsec) < 100]
```

> ```
>                rn  mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
> 1: Ford Pantera L 15.8   8  351 264 4.22 3.17 14.50  0  1    5    4
> 2:  Maserati Bora 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.60  0  1    5    8
> 3:     Camaro Z28 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.84 15.41  0  0    3    4
> 4:   Ferrari Dino 19.7   6  145 175 3.62 2.77 15.50  0  1    5    6
> 5:     Duster 360 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.57 15.84  0  0    3    4
> 6:      Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
> ```

Here, `as.data.table()` replaces `copy()`, `setDT()`, and `setorder()` in one go. Setting the key on `qsec` orders the rows in ascending order of `qsec` as requested by the OP. In addition, `data.table` *chaining* is used.

#### `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "rn") %>% 
  arrange(qsec) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(qsec) < 100)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 12
>   rn               mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
>   <chr>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 Ford Pantera L  15.8     8   351   264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     5     4
> 2 Maserati Bora   15       8   301   335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
> 3 Camaro Z28      13.3     8   350   245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     3     4
> 4 Ferrari Dino    19.7     6   145   175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     5     6
> 5 Duster 360      14.3     8   360   245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
> 6 Mazda RX4       21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
> ```

Comment: How to sum the filtered rows and insert a row showing only the summed values?